# About list.extend(tuple)

Tags: python, python-2.7

the code is here:

```
>>> a = ['xyz']
>>> b = (5,)
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> a
['xyz', 5]
```

I checked a lot of information,but they both told me that:

```
list.extend(seq)
seq -- This is the list of elements
```

I want know why list can extend a tuple.
thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `docstring` for `extend`, you will see that it can be extended by any iterable:

```
""" L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable """
```

This means you are not only limited to `list`s or `tuple`s, but also `string`s, `set`s, and other iterables:

```
for iterable in ('ab', set([1, 2, 3]), {1:2, 3:4}, (0, 1)):
    l = [1]
    l.extend(iterable)
    print(l)
```

This prints:

```
[1, 'a', 'b']
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3] # Note dictionaries iterate over keys by default
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

List method `extend` can extend a list instance from any iterable, and tuple is iterable. So it's the opposite of what you said, the tuple extends the list not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

It means exactly what it says, which is what you did: take a `list` and extend it by a sequence. It doesn't have to be exactly the `list` type. The resources you found could've been more clear on that point.

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) says the following:

> The operations in the following table are defined on mutable sequence types. The [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) ABC is provided to make it easier to correctly implement these operations on custom sequence types.
>
> In the table *s* is an instance of a mutable sequence type, *t* is any iterable object and *x* is an arbitrary object that meets any type and value restrictions imposed by *s* (for example, [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bytearray) only accepts integers that meet the value restriction `0 <= x <= 255`).

...

> ```
> s.extend(t) or s += t
> ```
>
> extends *s* with the contents of *t* (for the most part the same as `s[len(s):len(s)] = t`)

So, `a` from your example can be any mutable sequence type, like a `list`, and `b` can be any sequence, like a `tuple`.