# What is the difference between list += str and list += str,

Tags: python, string, list

Today I noticed a strange behavior while doing some python list operations.

Lets say,

```
a = []
b = 'xy'
```

When I do, a += b the interpreter returns:

```
a += b
a == ['x', 'y']
```

but when I do, a += b, (with a comma) the interpreter returns a = ['xy']

```
a += b,
a == ['xy']
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here.

Comment: @wim - Would you care to explain how this isn't a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  Sure, it's because `a += b` is not `list.extend(a, b)` (though the *result* is similar).  It's actually more like `a = a.__iadd__(b)`.

Comment: @wim - I'd say it is more like `list.extend`, as `list.__iadd__` modifies the list and also returns it, while `list.extend` only modifies the list but does not return it, and assignments like `a += b` don't return their assigned values as some other languages do.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, you're missing a subtlety in scoping here.  When you do `a+=b`, `list.__iadd__` modifies the list and also returns it, *and the returned object is bound again*.  To see why `+=` is not like an extend, consider the difference in behaviour of [these two functions](https://hastebin.com/uzihavivuh.py).

Comment: @wim - That's absolutely fantastic, but I still don't see how this question is anything but an exact duplicate. I mean, you even compare it to `list.extend` _in your answer here_. The answer to that question could serve equally well as an answer to this question, which is kind of what a duplicate is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About list.extend(tuple)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853946/about-list-extendtuple)

Comment: The distinction is important enough that closing as an exact duplicate of the one you've proposed would be sloppy/misleading.  However, you're correct that the other question is relevant.  And it's now "linked" in the sidebar, which is a more appropriate resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a += b
```

When `a` is a list, this operation is similar to `a.extend(b)`.  So it iterates the object `b`, appending each element to `a`.

If you iterate the string `'xy'`, it yields two elements `'x'` and `'y'`.

If you iterate the tuple `'xy',`, it yields one element `'xy'`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
a += b,
```

is equivalent to

```
a += (b, )
```

It creates a tuple with one item. If it is added, the item `'xy'` it added to `a`.

If you add a string like `'xy'` it counts as a sequence of characters on it's own and every sequence item (character) is added individually to `a`.

So basically the comma wraps `b` into a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Comma creates `tuple` - so `a += b,` means the same as `a += (b,)`

```
a += ('xy', )
```

You add tuple with one element so it almost like

```
a += ['xy']
```

so you have

```
a = [] + ['xy']
```

which gives result

```
a = ['xy']
```